# Comparing two values in shell script with hadoop

Tags: shell, hadoop

I want to check the directory availability in shell:

```
mypath=${BASELOGDIR}/${entity}/${YEAR}/${MONTH}/${DATE}
path2_check=`hdfs dfs -ls -d ${mypath} | awk '{print $2}'|head -1`

if [$path2_check -eq 1]; then
    echo ${path1_check}"availble"
fi
```

But I get the following error:

```
error :[1: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space after the '[' and a space before the ']' is needed:

```
if [ "$path2_check" -eq 1 ]
```

Also, assigning a command's output to a variable should be done like this:

```
var=$(command)
```

In your case:

```
path2_check=$(hdfs dfs -ls -d ........)
```